# How to update PolyCollection in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to know, if there is a way to redraw already created PolyCollection.

**MWP**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,1)

polycolelction = ax.fill_between(x, y)

for i in range(10):
    y = 1.2*np.sin(i*np.pi*x)

    # here should be data update, probably something like set_offset or set_verts?
    polycolelction.set_verts([x,y])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413223/how-do-i-get-a-fill-between-shape-in-funcanimation

Comment: That does not answer my question, since the polygon collection in that example is not redrawn, just created new every time.

Answer (score 1):

It could be easier to create the polygon from scratch and then update its vertices. That way, we have precise control over the number of vertices and how the polygon is represented.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

points = np.array([x, y]).T
points = np.vstack([points, [points[-1, 0], 0], [points[0, 0], 0]])
polycollection = PatchCollection([Polygon(points, closed=True)])
pathcollection = ax.add_collection(polycollection)
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.set_ylim(-1.3, 1.3)

for i in range(10):
    y = 1.2 * np.sin(i * np.pi * x)
    points = np.array([x, y]).T
    points = np.vstack([points, [points[-1, 0], 0], [points[0, 0], 0]])
    pathcollection.get_paths()[0].vertices = points
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

[image: fill_between animation]

Comment: I think that when you chose `closed = True`, at least in my configuration, you must add: `points = np.vstack([points, [points[-1, 0], 0], [points[0, 0], 0], points[-1]])`.